# Capybara drivers for different layouts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara

I have two drivers

- Desktop Version
- Mobile version

Mobile:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  args = []
  args << "-user-agent='Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143 Safari/601.1'"
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, :args => args)

end
```

Desktop:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end
```

and currently i add it for each test and it's a bit inconvenient.

I want to set it up in my `spec_helper`,but how i can do it?

The result should look like this:

```
if folder.mobile?
 use mobile driver 
else 
 desktop driver
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to switch drivers per test but the first step is to define your drivers with different names so you can switch between them rather than continuously redefining them

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_mobile do |app|
  args = []
  args << "-user-agent='Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143 Safari/601.1'"
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, :args => args)
end

Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end
```

Then assuming you are using the normal capybara/rspec config you can tag your mobile features with  driver: :selenium_mobile

```
feature "do something mobile", driver: :selenium_mobile do
  ...
end
```

or if you want to base it on the directory you can do something like

```
RSpec.before(:each) do |example|
  if self.class.include?(Capybara::DSL) and example.file_path.include?('mobile')
    Capybara.current_driver = :selenium_mobile
  end
end
```

The exact config needed would depend on how exactly you're configuring drivers for your non-mobile tests.

Comment: you solution is better

Answer (score 0):

i have done it

inside `spec_helper`

```
config.before(:each) do
  mobile = config.instance_variable_get(:@files_or_directories_to_run)[0].include?('mobile')
  if mobile
    Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
      args = []
      args << "-user-agent='Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143 Safari/601.1'"
      Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, :args => args)
    end
  else
    Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
      Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
    end
  end
end
```

upd:

it works only if you run tests separatly

for example

```
rspec spec/mobile/... etc
```

but if run just `rspec` it wan't work